# Show that if an edge e is on a cycle in the coherent Graph G, then it has to be an edge in a fundamental cycle in T, the spanning tree of G

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification, trees, fundamental-groups

**Definition fundamental cycle**: If $T$ is a spanning tree of a given graph $G$, and $e$ is an edge that does not belong to $T$, then the fundamental cycle $C_{e}$ defined by $e$ is the simple cycle consisting of $e$ together with the path in $T$ connecting the endpoints of $e$.
[image]

I feel like this should be done as a proof via contradiction, but I also feel like my solution is wrong:

Proof by contradiction, assumption: The edge does not lie on the fundamental Cycle in the spanning tree of $G$.

Then there are two vertices $a,b$ in $T$, that are connected by 3 Paths:

- The fundamental path, this is the only path in T that connects $a,b$ and
  always exists in a tree.
- The path $a,b$, which is the edge $\{a,b\}$ ($e$)
- Another path that is not the fundamental path nor the path $a,b$

But there is only one path in a Tree that connects two vertices, the fundamental path and only one edge that directly connects $a$ and $b$, the edge e. Therefore there can not be another path. Because both, the fundamental path and e lie on the fundamental cycle we have our contradiction.

Comment: The first conclusion, namely that $a$ and $b$ are connected by the fundamental path, seems to me to beg the question. The fundamental path is defined by it being in the fundamental cycle, which you are trying to prove the existence of.

Comment: Does this need a proof beyond `The fundamental path from $a$ to $b$ union the edge $\{a,b\}$ is a fundamental cycle containing $\{a,b\}$'? That seems perfectly sufficient to me.